# Calabash-android: application open browser and i can't get it any more

Tags: android, calabash-android

I am testing an Android application using `calabash` for Android.
The application open the browser after some treatment, and so I am losing control on my application. How can I go back to the app after the browser is opened and it's on foreground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have been redirected out of the app , you can bring it back from the background with the following command

```
    system("#{default_device.adb_command} shell am start  -n 'PATH_TO_ACTIVITY_IN_THE_SYSTEM' -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
```